# How to get rid of veth interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtual-network

I am not sure why / when, some `veth` interfaces have appeared in my system (`Ubuntu 16.0. LTS`):

```
» ifconfig | grep veth
veth4556676 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:b9:b9:ed:71:a6  
veth8747335 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:40:47:fd:1f:a7  
veth13905bf Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ae:73:8f:f7:9d:d4  
veth2636dd7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:b8:3c:d4:52:9c  
veth42de626 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:08:43:90:6e:f3  
veth4eedb05 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:5f:b8:e7:52:05  
veth7534db0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:9c:06:e6:f2:aa  
veth83508c7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5a:55:6c:ee:e5:7b  
veth8f275d6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:18:a1:52:7f:e9  
veth9f370c9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:9e:49:37:b4:16  
vethb96da94 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:11:90:11:8a:f4  
vethba463c9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:40:d5:9a:79:7a  
vethd820900 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a2:94:53:c8:53:bf  
vethdd077a0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:f9:00:93:05:5e  
vethef191e6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b2:b0:e1:68:50:7c  
vethf70a6f9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:a7:72:dd:88:69
```

This happens in a freshly rebooted system. I have two questions:

1. Why are those [veth](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/veth.4.html) interfaces present?
2. How can I get rid of them?

Note: I have lately been doing some Vagrant / VirtualBox related stuff, so that could be the reason.

Comment: veth interfaces are virtual interfaces used for bridging VMs - I'm not familiar with Vagrant, but I'd expect this is the cause - as this looks quite similar to what happens with Docker.

Comment: Certainly `veth` are virtual ethernet interfaces used for providing an internet connection to virtual machines.

Comment: @dangonfast, Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

#### Why are those `veth` interfaces present ?

Possibly because you are using a **Virtualization Platform** such as vmware or virtualbox or vagrant.

#### Getting rid of `veth` interfaces !

I suppose a better solution exists, but for the time being you can do it this way.

- Getting the name of `interfaces`

  ```
  ifconfig | grep "^veth" | cut -d' ' -f1
  ```

  Here `grep "^veth"` selects only those interfaces (listed by `ifconfig`) that start with `veth` and `cut` shows only the names by `d`elimiting the contents and showing only first `f`ield.
- Now we have to **shut down the drivers** for these interface using

  ```
  ifconfig vethxxxxxx down
  ```

  Also, you can do it by using `ip` command ( as suggested by [@dirkt in comments](https://superuser.com/users/327880/dirkt) ).

  ```
  ip link set $veth down
  ```

  But since there are too many of them, use `for` loop like this :

  ```
  for veth in $(ifconfig | grep "^veth" | cut -d' ' -f1)
  do
      ifconfig $veth down    # OR this ip link set $veth down
  done
  ```
- Here's one-liner for copy paste :

  ```
  for veth in $(ifconfig | grep "^veth" | cut -d' ' -f1); do ifconfig $veth down; done
  ```

Feel free to add in more stuff to the answer.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend using `ip` over the older `ifconfig` - `ip` can make use of network features of the kernel `ifconfig` can't use, though it's not important for this particular problem.

Comment: @dirkt, Thanks for your suggestion. As I don't use command much frequently, could you please edit the answer for using `ip` command. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @C0deDaedalus answer, the provided solution doesnt work completly for me, so I modified it to work wit `ip`:

### Bring *veth* Interfaces down

```
for veth in $(ip a | grep veth | cut -d' ' -f 2 | rev | cut -c2- | rev | cut -d '@' -f 1 )
do
    sudo ip link set $veth down
done
```

### Delete *veth* Interfaces

```
for veth in $(ip a | grep veth | cut -d' ' -f 2 | rev | cut -c2- | rev | cut -d '@' -f 1 )      
do
    sudo ip link delete $veth  
done
```

Depending on wether your root or not, you may keep the `sudo` or not

Comment: Your commands have extra unwanted text at the end.

Comment: @chx101 I removed it, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve the script (easy to read)

find interface name (choose one you like)

```bash
ip link | grep -Eo '\bveth\w+'

ifconfig | grep -Eo '^veth\w+'

ifconfig | grep '^veth' | cut -d':' -f1
```

turn down the interface

```bash
for f in `ifconfig | grep -Eo '^veth\w+'`;
  do echo === $f;
  sudo ifconfig $f up;
done
```

**NOTE**:
When I turn down those interface, my docker instance not working.

**About veth**:
https://vivek-syngh.medium.com/linux-virtual-ethernet-devices-aba9c3840d0d

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html